# Pandas: Reshaping records to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
    column1 column2 column3
    -----------------------
     a0      0.25   x1
     a0      0.05   x3
     a0      0.70   x2
     a1      0.25   x3
     a1      0.70   x2
     a1      0.05   x1
```

Trying to reshpe the `df` like below:

```
   column3   a0    a1
   ---------------------
    x1       0.25  0.05
    x2       0.7   0.70
    x3       0.05  0.25
```

Tried:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('column3').cumcount(), 'column3']).column2.unstack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use-

```
df.pivot(values='column2', index='column3', columns='column1')
```

**Output**

```
column1 a0  a1
column3     
x1  0.25    0.05
x2  0.70    0.70
x3  0.05    0.25
```

Use `rename_axis()` for resetting the index -

```
df.pivot(values='column2', index='column3', columns='column1').rename_axis(None)

column1 a0  a1
x1  0.25    0.05
x2  0.70    0.70
x3  0.05    0.25
```

Comment: how do we remove the `column1` label ?

Comment: @deadbug updated ans pls check

Comment: I think the link page explain everything related to the reshape @deadbug

Comment: @W-B Exactly. That is worth refering to.